# XSLT function with multiple inputs and multiple outputs

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

im trying to implement a function that takes as multiple inputs both nodes and items and also has many outputs, the transformed node and the other items. Im declaring my function like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://ecs.dgtaxud.ec" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:template name="Test">
        <xsl:param name="Trans" select="()" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="cont" select="()" as="item()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="num" select="()" as="item()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="Sl" select="()" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="id" select="()" as="item()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="GRef" select="()" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="dNum" select="()" as="item()*"/>
        <xsl:template match="Trans">
            <xsl:element name="{name(..)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="../(* except Sl)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want all the inputs that i declare to be outputs. Do you know if it is possible to declare outputs in the function?

Comment: That is all nonsense, to declare a function use `xsl:function`, so far you have defined a named template but inside you have another matching template and any `xsl:template` needs to be a top level element i.e. child of `xsl:stylesheet`, `xsl:template`s are never nested.

Comment: And declaring input parameters with names and types is fine but as you say you are writing a function that is supposed to return something you should also consider well what kind of result type you will have and create and declare that with e.g. `xsl:function as` (or, if you stick with the template, `xsl:template as`).

Comment: can an xsl:function has many outputs? im using mapforce of altova and i have to connect each ouput to a data item

Comment: Within the type system you can return any value so e.g. a sequence of anything, but sequences are always flat. In XSLT 3 you have more options with arrays (which can be nested) or with maps which can hold properties of other XDM values).

Comment: An XSLT stylesheet function produces only a single result, but that result can be a sequence, or in XSLT 3 it could be a map, or array, so in a sense your function could indeed produce multiple results.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: As with your initial question, this might be Altova MapForce specific so I would try to look into their documentation and tutorials or get in touch with their support if the documentation doesn't help.

Comment: https://www.altova.com/manual/Mapforce/mapforceenterprise/mf_func_udf_basics.html might be a start but I don't know what "Inline functions can have multiple outputs and thus return multiple values." refers to in terms of XSLT/XPath. I would think the explanation for "regular functions" with "Regular functions can have only one output. To return multiple values, you can declare the output to be of complex type (e.g., an XML structure), which would allow you to pass multiple values to the caller." is what applies to `xsl:function`s , but,as said, in XSLT 3, with arrays/maps, there are more ways.